# Using Datatables with output as map objects

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am trying to use the below example from datatables : https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html , but when i am trying to retrieve data from a url as map  , it is giving me error.

Below is the html code for this , i am hitting a mock api to get the object then iterating to get the object that datatable expect as input .

```
        <html>
          <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
        
            $(document).ready(function () {
              var completeObject = {} ; 
        var employeeArray = [] ; 
        
              $.getJSON('https://run.mocky.io/v3/3a65891c-84c8-467e-b2e9-ecb1629e1c45', function(json_data){
           $.each(json_data, function(k, v) {
            var tem_arr = [] ; 
            tem_arr.push(v['name']);
            tem_arr.push(v['position']);
            tem_arr.push(v['office']);
            tem_arr.push(v['extn']);
            tem_arr.push(v['start_date']);
            employeeArray.push(tem_arr);
        });
        
        console.log('check inner >>' + JSON.stringify(employeeArray) );
        $('#example').DataTable({
                data: employeeArray , 
                columns: [
                    { data: 'name' },
                    { data: 'position' },
                    { data: 'salary' },
                    { data: 'office' },
                    { data: 'extn' },
                    { data: 'start_date' },
                ],
              });
        
        });
        
        });
            </script>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div class="container">
              <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Position</th>
                      <th>Salary</th>
                     
                      <th>Office</th>
                      <th>Extn.</th>
        
                      <th>Start date</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Position</th>
                      <th>Salary</th>
        
                      <th>Office</th>
                      <th>Extn.</th>
                      <th>Start date</th>
                  </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
            </div>
         
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the JSON (as formatted text in the question) that you get back from the URL https://run.mocky.io/v3/3a65891c-84c8-467e-b2e9-ecb1629e1c45? Also, what error do you get? Just saying "_it is giving me error_" does not tell us much.

Comment: My guess is that you end up with an array of arrays `[ [...], [...], ... ]`. Therefore you cannot use column definitions such as `{ data: 'name' },` because you have discarded that key information from your source data. Instead, all you can do is give your columns titles such as `{ title, 'name' },` and so on. Note that this is what they do in that official "JS arrays" demo you linked to in your question.